# AngularJS multiple url params (ui-router)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, laravel, laravel-5, angular-ui-router

I have following format url returned from payment gateway:

```
#/app/booking/details?id=25&success=true&paymentId=123&token=xx2311&PayerID=QSWAA
```

Currently my route config as follow:

```
.state('app.booking.details', {
                url: '/details/:id/:paymentId',
                views: {
                    'mainView@app': {
                        templateUrl: 'views/details_booking.html'

                    }
                },
                css: ['assets/css/styles.css','assets/css/plugins.css'],
                resolve: loadSequence('bookingCtrl')


            })
```

Unfortunately I can't separate the url and pass it to server. How can I resolve these. So far only `id` is able to pass through. These are my Laravel 5.1 method:

```
public function getBookingDetailAPI(Request $request)
    {

        $oid = $request->input('paymentId'); --> null
        $oid = $request->input('id'); --> 25
        dd($oid);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your state `url` options of state should be changed to below as you are looking for query parameter from the `URL`.

```
url: '/details?id&paymentId&token&PayerID'
```

By this change you could get the `URL` parameter by `$stateParams` service injecting it into a controller like `$stateParams.id`, `$stateParams.paymentId`, etc.

Once you have that, you can then forward your request to your laravel server in your controller or resolve method, like this:

```
$http.get('/backend/route',{params:$stateParams}).then(function(data){
  console.log(data); // laravel response
});
```